# Composition of exponential function with discontinuous function

Tags: functions, continuity

Suppose $f(x)$ be a real discontinuous everywhere function. Then is $\exp(f(x))$ also discontinuous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g=\exp(f)$. Since $f$ is real, then $g$ is a positive function. But if $g$ were continuous at some $x$, then $f=\ln(g)$ would be continuous there, too (since the natural logarithm is defined and continuous on the positive reals). Thus, $g$ is discontinuous everywhere.

More generally, if we have functions $f_1,f_2$ such that $f_2\circ f_1$ "makes sense," and if we know that $f_2$ is invertible and has a continuous inverse, then $f_2\circ f_1$ is (dis)continuous in *exactly* the same places that $f_1$ is.

Comment: Thanks! I think i spent far too much time thinking about this already. You have saved me spending a lot more time!

Comment: Glad to help! :)